# Prolog why does this query return this particular result and what is its effect

Tags: prolog

```
?- assert(p(a)),assert(p(b)),setof(X,p(X),R).
X = H142
R = [a, b] 
yes
```

Whats the effect of this query and why does it return this particular result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the `yes` result is that R, i.e. the set made of just a and b is effectively the set of all Xs that satisfy p(x) predicate.

If you were to add elements to R or to remove a or b from it, the result would be `no`.

p(a) and p(b) are true because the assert predicates added these clauses to the database.

Similarly, keeping `R = [a, b]` if you were to add another clause, with say  `assert(p(c))`, the result would be `no`   (because R would be missing c to have *all* X which satisfy p(X)).

Comment: Note that `X` remains unbound after the call to `setof/3` because `X` is a "dummy variable" used to tell Prolog what solutions of the goal `p(X)` are to be collected in list `R`.  `setof/3` also allows a more complicated syntax when more than just one variable appears in the goal, so some variables' values can be combined in the list as compound terms and others can be bound or revised in backtracking.